# How do I print these return values from function in Python 3?

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, return

I have a homework assignment for raquetball simulation. I'm trying to figure out how to expand the program to account for shutouts and return the number for each player. I added a loop into the simNGames() to count the shutouts. I'd like to return those values and print them out in the summary.

```
    def simNGames(n, probA, probB):
    winsA = 0
    winsB = 0
    shutoutA = 0
    shutoutB = 0
    for i in range(n):
        scoreA, scoreB = simOneGame(probA, probB)
        if scoreA > scoreB:
            winsA = winsA + 1
        else:
            winsB = winsB + 1
    for i in range(n):
        scoreA, scoreB = simOneGame(probA, probB)
        if scoreA == 15 and scoreB == 0:
            shutoutA = shutoutA + 1
        if scoreA == 0 and scoreB == 15:
            shutoutB = shutoutB + 1

        return winsA, winsB, shutoutA, shutoutB ## The program breaks when I add
                                                ## shutoutA, and shutoutB as return val
```

If anyone could steer me in the right direction It'd be greatly appreciated. I get a ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2), when I add shutouts into the return value. Here is the entire program:

```
from random import random

def main():
    probA, probB, n = GetInputs()
    winsA, winsB = simNGames(n, probA, probB)
    PrintSummary(winsA, winsB)


def GetInputs():
    a = eval(input("What is the probability player A wins the serve? "))
    b = eval(input("What is the probablity player B wins the serve? "))
    n = eval(input("How many games are they playing? "))
    return a, b, n



def simNGames(n, probA, probB):
    winsA = 0
    winsB = 0
    shutoutA = 0
    shutoutB = 0
    for i in range(n):
        scoreA, scoreB = simOneGame(probA, probB)
        if scoreA > scoreB:
            winsA = winsA + 1
        else:
            winsB = winsB + 1
    for i in range(n):
        scoreA, scoreB = simOneGame(probA, probB)
        if scoreA == 15 and scoreB == 0:
            shutoutA = shutoutA + 1
        if scoreA == 0 and scoreB == 15:
            shutoutB = shutoutB + 1

        return winsA, winsB 

def simOneGame(probA, probB):
    serving = "A"
    scoreA = 0
    scoreB = 0
    while not gameOver(scoreA, scoreB):
        if serving == "A":
            if random() < probA:
                scoreA = scoreA + 1
            else:
                serving = "B"

        else:
            if random() < probB:
                scoreB = scoreB + 1
            else:
                serving = "A"
    return scoreA, scoreB

def gameOver(a, b):
    return a == 15 or b == 15

def PrintSummary(winsA, winsB):
    n = winsA + winsB
    print("\nGames simulated:", n)
    print("Wins for A: {0} ({1:0.1%})".format(winsA, winsA/n))
    print("Wins for B: {0} ({1:0.1%})".format(winsB, winsB/n))


if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

Answer (score 2):

When you call the function:

```
winsA, winsB = simNGames(n, probA, probB)
```

You're expecting only two values (winsA, winsB), but returning four.

Comment: @ Lee Daniel Crocker. Thank you! Using multiple functions can be very confusing.